# The exact value of $H_k(1)$, $H_k$ is the Hermite polynomial

Tags: combinations, factorial

Let $H_k(x)$ be the Hermite polynomial, which can be written in terms of Laguerre polynomial such as 
\begin{align*}
H_{k} \left( x \right) = H_{2k} \left( x \right) + H_{2k+1} \left(
x \right)\qquad \forall k\ge1
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
H_{2k} \left( x \right) = \left( { - 1} \right)^k 2^{2k} \left( k
\right)!\sum\limits_{j = 0}^{k} {\left( { - 1} \right)^j
\frac{{x^{2j} }}{{j!}}\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   {k - \frac{1}{2}}  \\
   {k - j}  \\
\end{array}} \right)}
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
H_{2k + 1} \left( x \right) = \left( { - 1} \right)^k 2^{2k + 1}
\left( k \right)!\sum\limits_{j = 0}^{k} {\left( { - 1}
\right)^j \frac{{x^{2j + 1} }}{{j!}}\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   { k + \frac{1}{2}}  \\
   {k  - j}  \\
\end{array}} \right)}.
\end{align*}
I tried to find a general formula for $H_k(1)$ but I couldn't do that!. The problem deals on how one can simplify a combinations with factorials. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The values of $H_k(1)$ corresponds to sequence $A062267$ in $OEIS$ and corresponds to the recurrence

$$a_n = 2\left(a_{n-1} - (n - 1)\,a_{n-2}\right)\qquad (a_0=1,a_1=2)$$

According to [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HermitePolynomial.html)

$$H_{2k}(1)=(-1)^k2^k (2 k-1)\text{!!}\, \, _1F_1\left(-k;\frac{1}{2};1\right)$$

$$H_{2k+1}(1)=(-1)^k 2^{k+1} (2 k+1)\text{!!}\, \, _1F_1\left(-k;\frac{3}{2};1\right)$$

Comment: yes, thank you very much. I was seeking a closed from. it's ok thanks